# Replace or hide elements based on url subdomain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, dom

Trying to replace and hide certain elements based on the subdomain. Example if the url is "www.uownrealestate.com" then load the normal site but if it is "justin2.uownrealestate.com" then hide the element containing an anchor link with the text "Agents".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var option = 'justin2';
    var full = window.location.host
    //window.location.host is subdomain.domain.com
    var parts = full.split('.')
    var subDomain = parts[0]
    var domain = parts[1]

    if (subDomain == option) {

        showDiv();
    }
});

function showDiv() {
    $("li:has(a:contains('Agents'))").hide();

}​
```

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var option = 'justin2';


var full = window.location.host
if(full.indexOf(option) > -1){
showDiv(); 
}
});
function showDiv() {
$("li:has(a:contains('Agents'))").hide();

}
```

still nothing is happening. any other suggestions? also this script is in an external js file. that shouldnt matter at all correct? Here is a snippit of the li element.

```
  <li><a href="only-at-uown.html">Only at uOwn</a>
    <ul>
<li><a href="showing-simulations.html"><span> Showing Simulations</span></a></li>
<li><a href="3d-mapping.html"><span> 3D Mapping</span></a></li>
<li><a href="solar-signs.html"><span> Solar-Powered Yard Signs</span></a></li>
<li><a href="paper-free-office.html"> Paper-Free Offices</a></li>
    <li><a href="prestige-package.html"> Prestige Package</a></li>
<li><a href="only-at-uown.html"> <em>Much more...</em></a></li>

    </ul>
   </li>


 <li><a href="realtors-agents.html">Agents</a></li>


 <li><a href="3d-showcase.html">3D Showcase</a></li>
```

Comment: sorry for not clarifying, but it seems as if nothing is happening. Either its not recognizing the subdomain correctly or the jquery to hide the element is incorrect I would assume

Comment: can you show your html snippet relevant to your code?

Comment: @GO3DExpansion works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/uEutE/.. uncomment/comment other part to test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.indexOf(`

```
var full = window.location.host;
if(full.indexOf(option) > -1){
   showDiv(); 
}
```

Comment: tried using indexOf and still nothing is happening when I load the page. Anything else you see that could be incorrect?

Comment: Try putting a debug point and check if it's passing the condition

Comment: @wirey hmmm it seems you are correct sir. I will check all my work and get back with what exactly went wrong! thank you for checking that for me!

Comment: So it seems that it will not work when linking to an external js file. Why is that so? Is there anyway to do this from a separate file? I'm trying my best to stay organized haha